# Code Signing Dlls using Azure Pipelines Powershell remote execution task

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, codesign, signtool

I am trying to signing dlls using signtool.exe. The problem i am having is signing certificate is mapped to one AD account and had to login to any accessible machine and do the signing process. The code signing certificate is stored in local user store and not on machine level certificate store. Issue is that I am able to sign the dlls after login in manualy RDP into machine with the code signing AD account which is mapped with code signing certificate but not able to replicate the same procedure using power shell remote execution task.
While doing, it says it cannot find the certificate even though the AD account used to login is having the code signing certificate. Certificate is located under **CurrentUser/My** path

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

The code snippet i am using for signing is below

> signtool.exe sign /s My /tr http://timestamp.entrust.net/TSS/RFC3161sha2TS "Test.ddl"
>
> SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + & 'C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' -NoLogo ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (SignTool Error:...given criteria. 
>     :String) [], RemoteException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Regards,
Renjith

Comment: What about using this Code Singing Task? You can get it 
 in https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stefankert.codesigning&targetId=398eccdc-4733-4661-99a6-dbe55158affc

Comment: @Renji Did you try Code sign task as suggested by Frank, any updates?

Comment: @Levi, I tried that earlier. But the code signign certificate resides in the windows certificate store and its non exportable to pfx format due to company policy security issue.